# Как установить кодировку для денвера?

Tags: denwer

Всем привет, подскажите, возможно ли сделать так, чтоб файлы html с кодировкой utf-8, хранящиеся на денвере отображали нормально кириллицу, если да, то как это сделать, в какой файл нужно залезть и что поменять там нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\WebServers\usr\local\apache\conf\httpd.conf

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Но всё-таки лучше в .htaccess  это дело прописывать. Надежней.

Comment: файл .htaccess самому делать или он где-та лежит? и если самому то где именно в корневой папке денвера или для каждого сайта отдельно

Comment: @Роман Соколов вам стоит лучше почитать на спец. сайте: http://www.htaccess.net.ru/doc/htaccess/index.php более, чем достаточно для первых шагов.

Comment: спасибо, очень полезная информация